# Uncaught Error: Class "Test\TestCase" not found running test with PHPStorm

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I'm using PHPUNIT 9.5 and I'm running tests with PHPStorm like I show in the following image

[image]

The test that I want to run is:

```
<?php     

namespace test\ccs\repository;          

use test\UnitTestCase;          

class SignInRepositoryTest extends UnitTestCase     {

   ...
   ...

}
```

Composer.json has:

```
 "autoload": {          
       "classmap": [                
          "app/controllers",                
          "app/models",                 
          "app/views"           
        ],         
        "psr-4": {          
          "ccs\\": "library/ccs/",                    
          "test\\": "tests/test/"             
        }
     },
```

When I run the test I got the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "test\UnitTestCase" not found
> in
> C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\application\ccsignin\tests\test\ccs\repository\SignInRepositoryTest.php:4
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\Util\FileLoader.php(66):
> include_once()
> #1 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\Util\FileLoader.php(49):
> PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load()
> #2 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php(397):
> PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad()
> #3 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php(527):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFile()
> #4 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php(98):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFiles()
> #5 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php(121):
> PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest()
> #6 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php(97):
> PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run()
> #7 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\phpunit(98): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
> #8 {main}
>
> Next PHPUnit\TextUI\RuntimeException: Class "test\UnitTestCase" not
> found in
> C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:99
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\phpunit(98): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
> #1 {main}   thrown in C:\inetpub\PublicPortal\vendors\PHPUnit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php
> on line 99

Answer (score 1):

Typically, tests are configured in the autoload-dev:

```yaml
"autoload": { ...},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "test\\": "tests/test/" ,
    }
},
```

And run
`composer dumpautoload -o`

Also, make sure that PhpStorm settings are correct, for example:

- Path to script: `/app/vendor/autoload.php`
- Default configuration file: `/app/phpunit.xml`
- Default bootstrap file: `/app/tests/bootstrap.php`